# Find & replace a character in a particular position

Tags: regex, r, replace

```
Comment
(apple (a) 100)
(orange 50)



Comment1
apple (a) 100
orange 50
```

I need to replace the starting open parenthesis & ending closing parenthesis with none using r.

Sample of my data is in "comment" field. My expected output is in "Comment1" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match the brackets at the beginning (`^\\(`) or (`|`) at the end (`\\)$`) and replace it with `""`.

```
gsub("^\\(|\\)$", "", Comment)
#[1] "apple (a) 100" "orange 50"
```

Or if it is based on position, we can place the characters that are needed in a capture group i.e. inside the brackets (`(.*)`) and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`).

```
sub(".(.*).", "\\1", Comment)
#[1] "apple (a) 100" "orange 50"
```

Or with `substring`

```
substring(Comment, 2, nchar(Comment)-1)
#[1] "apple (a) 100" "orange 50"
```

#### data

```
Comment <- c("(apple (a) 100)","(orange 50)")
```